# NodeJS puppeteer cookies fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to pull data from a website with puppeteer, but the cookies I added disappear after the page is opened.
and the session is suddenly dropped

```
const cookies = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/cookie');
const deserializedCookies = JSON.parse(cookies)
await page.setCookie(...deserializedCookies)
await page.goto(slugx, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```